# GTM create custom array out of datalayer

Tags: google-tag-manager

i have to get all sku's out of a data layer in gtm:

DataLayer looks like

```
{
  pageName: "cart",
  cart_total: "33.71",
  ecommerce: {
    items: [
      {
        item_name: "Product1",
        item_id: "123",
      },
      {
        item_name: "Product2",
        item_id: "456",
      },
      {
        item_name: "Product3",
        item_id: "789",
       
      }
    ]
  },
  customerId: "1234",
}
```

Output should be an array
item_id:"123,456,789"

I tried the following js:

```
function () {
item_id = []
for (i=0; i< ecommerce.items.length; i++) { 
    item_id.push(ecommerce.items.i.item_id); 
   }
return item_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that you want an array, but your example is a string. So, if you want a string, here:

```
DLObj.ecommerce.items.map(function(obj){return obj.item_id}).join()
```

If you want an array, just remove the join().

Here is the full code I used in testing:

```js
var DLObj = {
  pageName: "cart",
  cart_total: "33.71",
  ecommerce: {
    items: [
      {
        item_name: "Product1",
        item_id: "123",
      },
      {
        item_name: "Product2",
        item_id: "456",
      },
      {
        item_name: "Product3",
        item_id: "789",
       
      }
    ]
  },
  customerId: "1234",
};
DLObj.ecommerce.items.map(function(obj){return obj.item_id}).join()
```

you can certainly use it as a custom javascript variable in GTM, just wrap it in an anonymous function and return the required value as GTM asks you to do. Similar to this:

```js
function(){
  return DLObj.ecommerce.items.map(function(obj){return obj.item_id}).join();
}
```